# Broken images on CodeIgniter website after uploading to server

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, codeigniter, server

I uploaded my CodeIgniter website to the server, but after uploading the website layout is not working properly. Some images work, but other images are not showing.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The base URL in `config/config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.lalcoresidency.com/beta/';
```

Here is my website link: https://www.lalcoresidency.com/beta/

Comment: the site isnt working

Comment: i changed the path here is the link...   https://www.lalcoresidency.com/beta/lalcoresidency/

Comment: do you really have image at those paths. shows 404 for me

Comment: I have the image that path..

Comment: here is my .htaccess... RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /beta/lalcoresidency  

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/lalcoresidency/index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: can you show the directory having those assets and its path in a screenshot ?

Comment: please click this link for chat...  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113325/codeigniter-on-server

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to check that will help you trouble shoot.

The very first thing to do is to confirm that the image folders and files are actually on the server.

Try to figure out what the missing images have in common. Are they all in the same folder? If so, are permissions for that folder and its files set appropriately?

The owner of the folder(s)/file(s) will also need to be set appropriately. This will depend on the server. Many Apache based servers have the owner set to `www-data`.

Are any of the images loaded through css? For example, `background-image: url("images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png")`?  If so, confirm that the css file(s) are actually loading. Your browser's development tools will be invaluable for this. (Firefox uses *Firebug* and Chrome uses *Web Developer*)

I don't see any obvious problems with your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I dont have much knowledge about the server..this is first time i upload the website on the server

Comment: I just browsed to the link you provided and see that the file `style_new.css` failed to load. That should be the first problem to correct. The file is either not in the folder `/assets/css/` or is not named `style_new.css`.

Comment: that folder is empty

Comment: There are several other files loading correctly from that folder. For instance `https://www.lalcoresidency.com/beta/lalcoresidency/assets/css/style.css` is loading OK.

Comment: The link to the missing css is `https://www.lalcoresidency.com/beta/lalcoresidency/assets/css/style_new.css`

Comment: @Shubhank.. I done what you told me but the problem is same